# Can a single Nautilus window be started with multiple tabs?

Tags: nautilus, startup

When I fist start Nautilus I invariably open five favourite tabs..

I've tried multiple URIs from the command line, but it opened multiple windows.

Is it possible to somehow do this via command-line ?...

Comment: This doesn't appear possible, best thing to do here is probably file a wishlist bug upstream in Nautilus and see if someone will implement it.

Comment: @Jorge: Thanks... In that case, I've hacked a macro workaround, and posted the script as an answer

Comment: check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) with `--continue` option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Nautilus as a new tab in an existing window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-a-new-tab-in-an-existing-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per jorge's comment, the answer is "no"...

---

So as a side issue, because it's not a current option in Nautilus, I've cobbled together a script.. It suits me, given the situation.
I initially had some timing inssues which caused modifier-key states to go whacko, so I've added 100ms delays between steps, and it is now behaving itself on my system...
This may need to be changed in a different environment...
Here it is; at [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/566869/)

Comment: The script is no longer online... Can you place it online gain?

Comment: do you still have that script?

Comment: there is [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) now

Answer (score 4):

It is still unsupported by Nautilus itself, however you can use a script that admits several parameters to reuse or open a new instance of Nautilus if not running.

In order to use this solution you'll need to install pachages `wmctrl` and `xclip`. You can do it installing [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) and [xclip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xclip) using the Software Center (click on the links)  or via Terminal with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl xclip`.

Create a new file `nautab.sh` and add the following code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Nautilus opens folders in new tabs
# Dependencies: sudo apt-get install wmctrl xclip
# Pass directories as parameters, i.e. nautab /opt /var/log /usr/local/etc
# Wrong parameters will be shown as invalid directories
    
if [ "$(wmctrl -xl | grep "nautilus\.Nautilus")" == "" ]; then
    # wmctrl reports Nautilus not running
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        nautilus "$1" &
    else
        >&2 echo Not a directory: $1
        nautilus &
    fi
    shift
    # Nautilus takes some time to become responsive to automation
    sleep 2
fi 
#Save old clipboard value
oldclip="$(xclip -o -sel clip)"
for folder in "$@"
    {
    if [ -d "$folder" ]; then   
        echo -n $folder | xclip -i -sel clip
        wmctrl -xF -R nautilus.Nautilus && xdotool key --delay 120 ctrl+t ctrl+l ctrl+v Return
        # Use this if you suspect funny clipboard behaviour
        #xclip -verbose -o -sel clip
        #Leave some time before opening a new tab
        sleep 0.5
    else
        >&2 echo Not a directory: $folder 
    fi
}
#Restore old clipboard value
echo -n "$oldclip" | xclip -i -sel clip
```

This code is based is based on an answer to other [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window).

Run`nautab [directory]...` and new tabs will open on it. Note that there will be some delay; this is in order to wait for Nautilus to be responsive. Feel free to play with numbers.