# Open Nautilus as a new tab in an existing window

Tags: gnome, nautilus, window-manager, browser, tabs

Currently, if I click a launcher, shortcut icon, etc., I will get a new Nautilus window. If there is already a Nautilus window open, I would rather it open up in a new tab in the existing window (as if I had done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and browsed to the new location). How can I make this happen?

Comment: Some applications have a command-line option for this sort of thing, but I don't find anything like that for Nautilus. I agree that would be useful though.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a bash script and a launcher for that.

1. First, create the file:

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin && gedit ~/bin/nautilus-ctrl-t.sh
   ```
2. Then paste the following, and save:

   ```
   if [ "$(wmctrl -xl | grep "nautilus\.Nautilus")" == "" ]; then
       nautilus "$1" &
   else  
       #Save old clipboard value
       oldclip="$(xclip -o -sel clip)"

       echo -n "$1" | xclip -i -sel clip
       #wmctrl -xF -R nautilus.Nautilus && xdotool key "ctrl+t" "ctrl+l" && xdotool type "${1}" && xdotool key Return
       wmctrl -xF -R nautilus.Nautilus && xdotool key ctrl+t ctrl+l ctrl+v Return

       #Restore old clipboard value
       echo -n "$oldclip" | xclip -i -sel clip
   fi
   ```
3. Then run the command:

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x ~/bin/nautilus-ctrl-t.sh
   ```
4. Now, to create the launcher file, run this command:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/Nautilus-Ctrl-t.desktop
   ```
5. Paste the following, and save:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Nautilus-Ctrl-t
   Comment=Launches Nautilus if not yet, otherwise opens a new tab in it
   Categories=FileManager;GNOME;
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/system-file-manager.png
   Exec=/bin/bash -c ~/bin/nautilus-ctrl-t.sh
   Terminal=false
   ```
6. Log out, or restart to update the application list and you're done.

Try that. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Added a location as a script parameter

**UPDATE 2**

Replaced xdotool type with  xclip

**UPDATE 3**

Cleaned up the process by adding numbers. Added mkdir command. Updated the first "if statement" because if nautilus is managing the desktop, it will have a pid, but no active window, so better to use wmctrl. Added quotes around the first argument in case there are spaces. Changed the icon for nautilus to be system default in the .desktop file.

Comment: You'll need to install xdotool and wmctrl for that script to work, as they're not installed by default.

Comment: Well, it's a dirty hack, but I hope it'll work in most cases :) Can you please add passing location as the argument? It looks like possible with "Ctrl+L", insert passed address, "Enter"...

Comment: I'm awarding desgua right now, but I promise you another bounty if you will add custom location opening to your script :)

Comment: Added a location as a script parameter.

Comment: Ok, I've started a bounty for you, but AFAIU I can't award two bounties in one day :) There's a space missing after $pid and it doesn't work for inode/directory MIME type for me. Can you please add instructions on how to make it work for desktop shortcuts? Another suggestion is to use xclip for pasting location to avoid triggering some actions if Ctrl+L fails :)

Comment: Added a space.
Do you mean how make it work for existing nautilus shortcuts, or how to create a new shortcut to some folder opening?
I'll try xclip in the evening.

Comment: As I see *wmctrl key* does the same as *xclip*. Doesn't it?
What kind of shortcuts do you mean?

Comment: I meant to replace nautilus with this script as default inode/directory handler :) `xclip` instead of `xdotool type`

Comment: I have no idea how to utilise xclip instead of wmctrl, cause wmctrl deals with *windows and X11 events*, while xclip deals with *clipboard and stdin/stdout* which are rather different interfaces. Why not you assign promised bounty?

Comment: The system didn't allow me to award twice in one day. Here you go :) But don't misinterpret me, I've never said about replacing wmctrl with xclip, did I? xclip is the clipboard manager, I'm suggesting to replace xdotool type with it :) (the problem is that xdotool type cannot type some characters and it's generally safer and faster to just paste the address instead of typing it)

Comment: I will try to fix it myself later, don't worry ;)

Comment: Ok, I get. I updated the script - changed *xdotool type* to *xclip*. Thanks.

Comment: This script is not quite working for me.  It does open a new tab if nautilus is already open, but it doesn't start a new window otherwise.  And I was not able to see how to make it open a custom location

Comment: try to use ctrl+shift+t as [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) script does with `--continue` option, will work much better and much faster

Comment: I have installed `xdotool`, `wmctrl` and `wclick`. I have executed `exo-preferred-applications` to set `~/bin/nautilus-ctrl-t.sh` as the default file manager. Unfortunately, when I click on folders placed in the desktop they are opened in different windows. Also, the same folder is opened in a new tab when I open a different folder! Do you know another file browser able to do that without scripting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/586503/any-file-browser-well-integrated-into-ubuntu-14-04lts-desktop-able-to-open-deskt

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is not possible as
1) It is a [suggested idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/16715) at [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) that wasn't implemented yet,
2) And supposedly after analyzing the source code [Shiki](https://superuser.com/users/16001/shiki) didn't find [a way to pass this call to nautilus](https://superuser.com/questions/140694/how-to-open-some-location-in-new-tab-in-existing-nautilus-window-from-console).

Comment: Thank you. Although the others answers are also interesting ;-)

Comment: Yes, they are all good in some way :) And zuba will get another bounty if his hack will fix the initial issue :)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixable very easily in [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.2 by going into the Nautilus preferences, on the "Behavior" tab and clicking the box called "Always open in browser windows".

You will know it worked because from that point on, in your folder browsing window, you will see a left hand nav on the window which is the method that Nautilus uses to "re-use" the explorer window.

So, basically, all you need to figure out is "how to enable the left-hand navigation menu in a Nautilus browser window".

Comment: That's an interesting info, thanks :) What is the version of Nautilus in CentOS 6.2?

Comment: That would be 2.28.4 which is for Gnome-2 (GTK+2).

Comment: That being the case, it sounds like there is no solution for Gnome-3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever [desgua said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window/123585#123585) is somewhat right.

One option you have is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in the same window.

Or press <kbd>F3</kbd> in Nautilus for **split view**.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but it's not about opening new tabs from within Nautilus :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the bash script above as a starting (thank you!), I created a one-window per workspace script, ThunarTab, specifically for Thunar in XFCE. The script also allows opening multiple directories at once using the "Open All" context menu on the Desktop. I give a detailed description and a downloadable file of it at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=244076 "[Tutorial] Improving Thunar in XFCE by opening new tabs instead of windows with Bash."