# What is the command to open a specific directory in a new tab in nautilus?

Tags: command-line, scripts, nautilus, launcher

I want to make a `.desktop` file that opens a folder in my default file manager in a new tab. To test if it opened the right location, I tried `nautilus ~/*folder*`. That opens my file manager, but it says that something went wrong. The same happens when I use `nautilus /home/*username*/*folder*`. What command can I use to open a specific folder in home in a new tab from a `.desktop` file?

My goal is to have an icon on my dock (plank) that opens the map ~/Downloads in a new tab in Nautilus.

Comment: Do you want a new tab or a new window?

Comment: nautilus does not support opening a directory in a *new tab* from command line, only in a new *window*. It can be faked however, but what is the error it gives? (could you @ping me if you addres a comment to me, or anyone else? Otherwise I'd have to keep all posts opened :) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [open nautilus as new tab in existing window](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window)

Comment: @n0noob and other voters (@muru?): There is a subtle difference: the supposed dupe asks for opening new directories *anyway*, not about opening a specific *directory* in a new tab. The answer there offers to do that, (although dupes are about *questions*), but moreover, I couldn't get it working there.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, and I voted to close as that is a more general question, with a possible merging of questions to get your answer there.

Comment: @muru I agree the *answer* there could possibly cover this one, but it doesn't as far as I can see (tried). The *question* however does not, and opening a specific directory requires a more extensive number of steps. I think the supposed dupe is fit for a more  limited number of situations; while leaving out a number of lines *here* will cover the supposed dupe question (will post here if I get home).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Then we are reading the questions very differently. OP wants to create a launcher that when clicked opens a new tab. The dupe: "if I click a launcher/shortcut icon etc i will get a new nautilus window. If there is already a nautilus window open, I would rather it open up in a new tab" - the only difference is that they already have a launcher. What the answer there says right now, I don't know and don't care.

Comment: @muru Differently indeed: *My goal is to have an icon on my dock (plank) that opens the map ~/Downloads in a new tab in Nautilus.*  That is: *opening a tab in a specific directory*

Comment: @JacobVlijm What do you imagine the shortcut icon in the other question does? Open in random directories?

Comment: @muru, well, not in a controlled directory anyway (and not in `~/Downloads`)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Come to [chat].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24127/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-muru).

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT:

As a result of ongoing insight, below an improved version of the script.

Due to the fact that the script now *pastes* the path instead of *typing* it (using `xdotool`), the script is more reliable. Although the script is not *actually* faster (consider it *is* a work around, due to nautilus' lack of cli options) the script "feels" more "crispy". Fact remains however that the script simply needs to wait for the GUI to be ready for each next step, since it simulates user actions. Timing inside the script is on the save side; on faster systems, one might be able to do some optimization.

Use the script exactly as explained in the original answer; it (still) needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` to be installed. This version furthermore rquires `xclip`:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

#### The new version of the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import time

arg = sys.argv[1:]
arg = arg[0] if arg else ""

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

try:
    pid = get(["pidof", "nautilus"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    wlist = []    
else:
    wlist = [l for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if pid in l\
             and "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in get(["xprop", "-id", l.split()[0]])]

if wlist:
    w = wlist[-1].split()[0]
    subprocess.call(["wmctrl", "-ia", w])
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "printf '"+arg+"' | xclip -selection clipboard"])
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+t"])
    time.sleep(0.4)
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+l"])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+v"])
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "key", "Return"])

else:
    subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", arg])
```

---

### Old answer:

Nautilus does not have a command line option to open a new tab, however, you can "fake" it with the help of a script, using `xdotool` and `wmctrl`.

#### How to use

1. Install (if necessary) both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `nautilus_tab` (no extension) in `~/bin`, and *make it executable*.
   If the directory `~/bin` didn't exist yet, create it, and run `source ~/.profile` to make the directory "show up" in `$PATH`. (or alternatively, log out/in)
3. Test-run it by running the command:

   ```
   nautilus_tab <directory>
   ```

   It should:

   - if no nautilus window is open, open a new nautilus window in the directory
   - if a window *is open*, open a new tab in the directory

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd)

try:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
except:
    arg = ""

try:
    pid = get(["pidof", "nautilus"]).strip()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    run(["nautilus ", arg])
else:
    w = [l.split() for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if pid in l][-1]
    print(w)
    w_id = w[0]   
    if len([l for l in get(["xprop", "-id", w_id]).splitlines() if all(
        ["_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM)" in l, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in l])]) != 0:
        run(["wmctrl", "-ia", w[0]]); time.sleep(0.1)
        run(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+t"])
        if arg != "":
            run(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+l"])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            run(["xdotool", "type", arg])
            time.sleep(0.02*len(arg))
            run(["xdotool", "key", "Return"])
    else:
        run(["nautilus", arg])
```

#### Notes

- The script is a workaround, to simulate user actions. As a result, the timing "inside" the script is important. I set timing to "safe" values on my system, and made it "smart" if possible. If it might not work correctly on your system, leave a comment.
- The script will possibly brake if the targeted window (to add the tab to) is on another workspace
- In case of directories with spaces, use quotes:

  ```
  nautilus_tab '</directory/with spaces>'
  ```

If no argument (-directory) is used, the script will open a new tab in the same directory as the currently opened `nautilus` window. If no `nautilus window was opened, a new window will open in your home directory.

Comment: @MaudKon Just curious, but did you try it?

Comment: Perhaps you should go back to using proper lists for `call` instead of `[bash, -c, "big huge command"]`

Comment: @mure done, hardly remember writing it. Works fine though.

Comment: Interesting, I could get the bash script working simply with Exec in desktop file written without `/bin/bash -c ` and with full path instead of `~`. On the other hand, I can see your script working very slowly with commands `Ctrl+L` and `Ctrl+V` (and also see that we need `Ctrl+T` before those to open a New Tab). How can we make it run faster please?

Comment: @Sadi Not sure where you find `/bin/bash` in my code? Thanks for mentioning the speed issue. This post is from quite a while ago, relatively, ongoing insight makes me use *pasting* text instead of typing these days. The fact remains however that the cleanest (and fastest) option is not available, since `nautilus`' cli options are quite limited.  I will edit if I get home.

Comment: Thanks, the bash command is in the other (bash) script mentioned above, sorry for the confusion 

Comment: Hi @Sadi updated. See the remark in the updated section.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works much better now. BTW have you looked at the bash script here (http://askubuntu.com/a/123801/47343)? I've also tried it before I saw this, and it seems to work a little faster, but a little buggy, (e.g. sometimes not catching the path right) I guess this might be related with what you call "a safe speed" ;-)

Comment: @Sadi exactly. The timing needs to be surprisingly slow on this system, but I need to try on my other systems once I can (tomorrow). This is my 12 years old laptop :) Wow, never noticed the link!

Comment: It looks fine on my system; only very sharp eyes can see the action now ; -) Also love your QLE here (https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/qle) by the way -- Ubuntu should incorporate it into Unity ; -)

Comment: @Sadi great that you found qle! It was my very first project *ever*. I am working on a new version, but the old version still works fine over the Ubuntu versions since 11.04 :)

Answer (score 0):

(These sites drive me crazy with their weird requirements - this should be a comment, but I don’t have enough reputation and this kind of nonsense doesn’t encourage me to get it!)

Jacob’s answer does not work for paths with spaces in them. It requires two changes...

```
run("nautilus "+arg)
run('nautilus "'+arg+'"')

run("xdotool type "+arg)
run('xdotool type "'+arg+'"')
```

I run it with Thunar though and it doesn’t interpret `~` well. E.g. `thunar-tab.py "~/Documents"` will produce an error that `/home/user/~/Documents` cannot be found. You have to call it with an explicit path.

Comment: Try without quoting  `~`: `thunar-tab.py ~/Documents`

Comment: Since my aim is to support paths with spaces, quoting is required.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to quote the entire thing: `~/"foo bar"/'blah!blah'`

Comment: I think that’s getting *more* complicated than just putting the home folder in a script file several times.

Comment: If you're calling it from a script, make use of the `$HOME` variable: `"$HOME/foo bar"`.

Comment: I think if you have something constructive to add maybe you could write another answer since this seems to be drifting away from the original question.

Comment: Which suggestion? You don't seem to be trying out anything I suggest.