# Terminal default new tab

Tags: command-line, bash

Whenever I've got a running terminal instance and for example go into my file manager and right click "open in terminal" a new terminal instance starts.

How can I change it so that a new tab opens in the already existing terminal instance?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with gnome desktop.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: With default gnome-terminal in standard Ubuntu, it probably still is not possible. A hack was suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-a-new-tab-in-an-existing-window. However indeed, specify which desktop environment you use.

Comment: If there are two terminal open, what do you want it to do? where should the new tab be opened?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved on `thunar` and `xfce4-terminal` File manager.

(It can also be achieved on Nautilus and `xfce4-terminal`, but you will have to install `filemanager-actions`. I have explained both)

On Thunar, click on `edit`->`Configure custom actions...`

[image]

Create new action by clicking on <kbd>+</kbd> and fill as given below.

Give the command as:

```
xfce4-terminal --tab --working-directory=%f
```

Set an icon of your choice.

In `Appearance Conditions` tab, check Directories.

and Save.
[image]

You should get it on your right click menu:

[image]

**NOTE:** Doing similar steps on Nautilus with `filemanager-actions` for `gnome-terminal` creates a new window instead of new tab. But it works fine with `xfce4-terminal`.

For **nautilus**:

Install  `filemanager-actions`

```
sudo apt install filemanager-actions
```

Open `filemanager-actions`

Create a new action.

[image]

Choose an icon, check all those options.

[image]

set path as `xfce4-terminal`

and parameters `--tab --working-directory="%d"`

and save.

It should show up on your right click menu like this:

[image]

---

If you want this behavior to be the default, you can achieve it my setting alias for `gnome-terminal` as `gnome-terminal --tab` in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you Severus. But I was looking for a more general solution. So if I want to open a new terminal wherever and one already exists the new one will be a new tab by default. Do you have an idea how that might work?

Comment: @Grumpy How do you open terminals? You could just alias `gnome-terminal` to `gnome-terminal --tab` in your `/etc/bashrc` (for all users) or set keyboard shortcut ctrl +alt +T to `gnome-terminal --tab`.