# Is there a way to reopen Nautilus tabs (directories path) after reboot?

Tags: nautilus, tabs

I am looking for a solution to reopen multiple directory tabs opened in nautilus window after system reboot automatically (possibly via an extension in Nautilus if there is any).

Here is the situation:
I usually have multiple Nautilus (File Manager) windows opened with multiple tabs within each of them. After reboot, I have to reopen all the directories that was previously opened in the windows and their tabs.

I need a solution to tell Nautilus to remember the tabs' path and open them after reboot. Same functionality as what internet browser does (Countinue where you left off).

I appreciate to suggest me another file manager who does it in case Nautilus unable to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Nautilus as a new tab in an existing window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-a-new-tab-in-an-existing-window)

Comment: See the old question I marked this as a duplicate. Unfortunately, that is still true. There are no command line options to open a new tab. Eventually, one could hack simulating keyboard events as in the other question, but it is ugly.

Comment: Similar answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26042/can-a-single-nautilus-window-be-started-with-multiple-tabs

Comment: I didn't explain the situation well and edited the original question already to add more clarity to it. The suggested answers are not what I need but have similarities. Thank you anyways @vanadium

Comment: OK, you see that it is important to formulate your actual issue accurately.